# How to have a custom floatproperty based on the selected face? (Knowing that it is not possible)2.8

Tags: python, faces, properties, panel

Reading here and I saw that there is no possibility of having a custom property based on a selected face, but in blender I think you can do "Hackerate" and fly over this problem. I think for example, creating a FaceMap,or a temporary vertex group and to base the properties on these objects bpy.types, I am probably wrong, but I would like to have an opinion from some fan of these experiments. I would create different problems with these methods I believe, has anyone got to try it?

Have float property registered in a class like:

```
class MY_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):

bl_label = "blah"
bl_idname = "blah"
bl_space_type = "blah"
bl_region_type = "blah"
bl_category = "blah"


def draw(self, context):
    ob = bpy.context.active_object
    ###how to get property ?
    layout = self.layout               
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(##??##, 'my_float', text="")

class Myproperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_float: FloatProperty(default=0)

def register():
    from bpy.types import ##best type##
    ##best type##.faceproperty = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Myproperty)
```

I read about bmesh method but not understand if that information they are right for me : https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_release/bmesh.html

I have also seen looked at among the bpy.types. in the python console there is also bpy.types.SelectedUvElement
and bpy.types.UVLoopLayers
Assuming there is a uv, would I have the ability to customize the face property based on an uv layer?

Edit:
I would like to clarify that the use of the selected face is clearly useful in edit mode and on the use of a FloatProperty slider, so I would like the values on each face to remain recorded once interacted

To make me understand better, I would like to get this property as you would with a bpy.types.Object

like to in register:

```
from bpy.types import Object

Object.example_property = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Myproperty)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mesh data layers**

Mesh components, faces, edges and vertices, can have custom data layers. A float can be assigned to each face in a mesh with [custom face float layer](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.polygon_layers_float)

In object mode the index of the active face is `me.polygons.active`  and in `bmesh` the active face is `bm.faces.active`, which will be None if no face is active.

Here is a simple test script.  Run in object mode. Adds a custom float layer, and sets the value of the active face to 5. Switches to edit mode, prints the layer float value of the active face.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data

# add a float layer to faces
float_layer = me.polygon_layers_float.new(name="float_layer")

# set the value of the active face to 5.0

float_layer.data[me.polygons.active].value = 5
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
# get the float layer
float_layer = bm.faces.layers.float.get(float_layer.name)

af = bm.faces.active
if af:
    print(af[float_layer])
```

UV is also a mesh layer, associated with face loops (each uv face has its own set of 2d coordinate verts, whereas mesh faces, if connected,  share verts with other faces at edges)  For an example see ***`Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator Mesh UV`***

**Property and Panel**

Since the property attains to a mesh, possibly a good idea to make it a `bpy.types.Mesh` property.

Have made an edit mode bmesh property on the panel. The poll method will set it, and clear it when in object mode.  The mesh needs a "float_layer" as explained above. *Run the code above to add a face float layer to the active mesh object*

The poll method is required to attach a live edit bmesh to the panel when the object enters edit mode (polls).

[image]

```
import bpy
import bmesh

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Mesh properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "data"
    ebm = dict()

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        if context.mode == 'EDIT_MESH':
            me = context.edit_object.data
            fl = me.polygon_layers_float.get("float_layer")

            if fl:
                cls.ebm.setdefault(me.name, bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me))
                return True

        cls.ebm.clear()
        return False

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        me = context.edit_object.data
        layout.prop(me, "float_value")

def set_float(self, value):

    bm = HelloWorldPanel.ebm.setdefault(self.name, bmesh.from_edit_mesh(self))

    # get the float layer
    float_layer = bm.faces.layers.float.get("float_layer")

    af = bm.faces.active
    if af:
        af[float_layer] = value
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(self)


def get_float(self):        
    bm = HelloWorldPanel.ebm.setdefault(self.name, bmesh.from_edit_mesh(self))

    # get the float layer
    float_layer = bm.faces.layers.float.get("float_layer")

    af = bm.faces.active
    if af:
        return(af[float_layer])
    #bm.free()

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Mesh.float_value = bpy.props.FloatProperty(get=get_float, set=set_float)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

*Script designed for 2.8 can confirm also runs in 2.79*

Comment: Ty batFINGER,so thanks to you I realized that you can do it but i not understand how to register floatproperty in classs with bpy.types in register, and how put in ui panel row.prop(##your_example.faceproperty##,'my_float', text='Ty bat') like to edit mode, if i understand well only bmesh in edit mode?

Comment: I edited the question, because my problem is also how to handle this with a ui panel and a float slider, I have no experience on the faces and I am completely unable to get the necessary information correctly.

Comment: So I thank you for this interest, I didn't think it was so complex and I understand very little (I have no confidence with this method at all)
I already have a panel that must always be visible, so I suppose I'll have to change something, but I know that in blender 2.8 this doesn't work and in blender 2.79 it reports an error that I can't identify (im poor knowledge of the method) error Text in line 17, 52 and 44

Comment: Can the @classmetod be avoided?

Comment: No, needs the poll.   There was a cut-n-paste error on line 17.  Can confirm (via gif) working on both 2.79 and 2.8  Polls in edit mode. Could be modified to also work in object mode.

Comment: I apologize if I insist, I copied and pasted, but nothing appears, if gate fl = me.polygon_layers_float.get ('float_layer') the 'q marks' the float appears, but rightly give error 'name'. Isn't that your class has been recorded and is that why it works properly for you?

Comment: I can open a new file in either 2.79 or 2.8, with the cube active,  run the two scripts  above (either order)  and it works as expected (as displayed above) . I have no idea what you mean re q marks and classes being recorded.

Comment: So if I just run the second  code it doesn't work, if instead I run the second code and  then the first code  works. I apologize but I'm using google translate and sometimes I think it misleads my concepts

Comment: So batFINGER, this script work fine,but i already have a panel, and the @classmethod poll no longer allows me to view it. I can create another class that automatically assigns float_layer = bm.faces.layers.float.get (float_layer.name)
and give me back what the classmethod does?
I was thinking of hiding the menu under a Bolean button, so this script will execute it only if the Bolean button is active,
I think this is another question, do you advise me to post it as a new question?